# edit 3D animations in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm studying this example
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2_control.html
found on this site:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/
1) What should I change in the html file to run the animation "jump"?
2) Where can I find the files that contain the rules for the animation of the character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given example is ment for user to control the movement by keyboard input. If you look closely you'll see an eventlistener that allows you to make the charaters run by pressing 'W'.

Comment: with w the characters go on
with "c", "space" and "ctrl" should jump, attack, etc. ...
I uncommented the relevant lines in the functions "onKeyDown" and "onKeyUp" but do nothing ...

Comment: I guess that the animation isn't implemented, check the `ogro-light.js` file in the model/animated/ogro folder